# Ansible - connect via ssh proxy (Socks4)

Tags: ssh, ansible, socks

I'm trying to figure out how to make Ansible connect to nodes via Sock4 proxy.

I would expect to fill in `ansible_ssh_common_args` paramameter in the Ansible hosts file in some way.

something like this:

```
[my-env]
<SOME_IP> ansible_ssh_common_args='ProxyCommand="/bin/nc -X 4 connect -x <PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT> %h %p"'
```

Is there any way to make ansible connect to nodes via sock4 proxy?

Answer (score 2):

I missed out on the `-o` in the command

this works out fine:

```
[my_env]
<SOME_IP> ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="/bin/nc -x <PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT> %h %p"'
```

Comment: where do you put this? in ansible.cfg file? as a environment variable ie export nsible_ssh_common_args='-o "ProxyCommand ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i ~/.ssh/gcp-default-key -W %h:%p vagrant@34.89.221.226"'  or other?